# ¿Como crear tres estrella mas una estrella media sin :hover?

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo problemas en los estilos `CSS` estoy queriendo mostrar tres estrellas más una mita de una estrella sin `:hover`

**Ejemplo:**

```css
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px; 
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3KS.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:hover {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:hover {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-rating">
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

> He probado en quitarle el `:hover` pero al quitarle el `:hover` hace que se muestra todas las 5 estrellas de color amarillo sin mostrarme la mita de una estrella

---

**Nota:** Todo cambio debe controlarse o aplicarse mediante el archivo de los estilos .css no dependiente es decir no agregando estilos en las etiquetas html todo debe ser desde el archivo style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es utilizar `:before`

Cambia esto:

```
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:before {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:before {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

Por esto:

```
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:before {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:before {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes poner eslilo a esa estrella y quitarle el hover con esta propiedad:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

La propiedad pointer-events permite controlar si un elemento puede o no recibir los eventos del cursor con independencia del orden de apilación (su valor de z-index).

Dicho de otra forma: si es invisible al puntero o no.

```css
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px; 
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3KS.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:hover {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:hover {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-rating">
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" style="pointer-events:none;" data-index="7"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a ultima estrella tiene `:hover `  y todo debe controlarse mediante los estilos css no dependiente es decir agregando estilos en las etiquetas html todo debe ser desde el archivo .css

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes puedes hacer es seleccionar los `<li>` que requieras y aplicarles la propiedad `pointer-events:none !important;`. Puedes seleccionarlos de muchas formas como por ejemplo por medio de su atributo `data-index`, como puedes notar este atributo es único para cada uno por los cual no habrá ningún problema.

**NOTA:** también puedes seleccionar los `<li>` utilizando `nth-child()` o simplemente añadiendo una clase especial a cada uno, en fin hay muchísimas formas en las que puedes lograr tu objetivo

Acá te dejo una de las tantas formas en las que se puede dar solución a tu problema.

```css
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px; 
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3KS.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:hover {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:hover {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}

li[data-index="7"],
li[data-index="8"],
li[data-index="9"]{
  pointer-events:none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-rating">
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Y esta otra forma que es totalmente válida:

```css
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px; 
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3KS.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:hover {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:hover {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}

.c-rating__item:nth-child(8),
.c-rating__item:nth-child(9),
.c-rating__item:nth-child(10){
  pointer-events:none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-rating">
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Te adjunto una imagen donde puedes ver desde que versión los navegadores admiten esta propiedad css:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**OTRA SOLUCIÓN UTILIZANDO LOS ESTILOS EXISTENTES**

Pero como te digo si o si debes agregar más líneas de código

```css
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px; 
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3KS.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active,
.c-rating__item:hover {
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active,
.c-rating__item.left:hover {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}

.c-rating__item:nth-child(8),
.c-rating__item:nth-child(10){
  background-position: -12px 0px !important;
}

.c-rating__item:nth-child(9){
    background-position: 0px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-rating">
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

**EXPLICACIÓN:** Esta otra forma lo que hace es obligar a los últimos `<li>` a mantener la posición inicial de su `background-image` ignorando el `:hover`

---

Para tu solución teniendo en cuenta el dinamismo de las estrellas simplemente deberías de quitar las líneas del `:hover` y listo

```css
.c-rating {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 12px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 12px; 
    flex: 0 0 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background-position: -12px 0px;
    background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3KS.svg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.left {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.c-rating__item.is-active{
    background-position: -36px 0;
}
.c-rating__item.left.is-active{
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-rating">
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No me ayuda el contenido HTML es generado con PHP y por ello tiene estilos por defecto, todo debe hacerse con los mismo estilos.

Comment: Desde mi conocimiento **SI** o **SI** debes agregar estilos nuevos, o agregar clases para diferenciar los últimos `<li>` no veo como más lo puedas hacer, además como estás cargando tu vista? sin importar como se cargue no debe haber impedimento en agregar algo nuevo

Comment: las estrellas son generadas automáticas con PHP según los votos por lo tanto sería un dolor de cabeza tener que agregar estilos manualmente a parte eso tendría que hacerlo cada vez que el voto suba entonces no es una solución existe algún otro método en vez de :hover ese es el unico problema el :hover

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta con otra solución válida, pero te reitero sea cual sea la solución debes agregar más lineas de estilos

Comment: Ah ya te entiendo...

Comment: tampo es una solución estarías en la misma, ahora que ya entiendes espero tenga una solución :)

Comment: Te acabé de editar con otra solución, mira si te sirve esa ! :)